# Can I attach a unique, run time determined tag to a selection of objects?

Tags: haskell, types, subtyping

Consider type `B` and its subtype `A`, determined by a predicate `P`. An instance would be natural numbers for `B` and prime numbers for `A`, with some primality test as `P`. It is straightforward to implement a smart constructor for such `A`, defined as a `newtype` or a `Tagged`.

Now suppose the subtyping predicate is not completely determined at compile time. For example, let `P` be membership in a collection determined by `IO` input: the operator enters the coefficients for an integral polynomial and we obtain a predicate that verifies that a given number is a value of that polynomial at some index.

**Can I make sure that each polynomial, and the values validated for it, are tagged in a fashion that makes them compatible with each other and incompatible with any other polynomial?** Among the operations I am going to need is conversion between values and their indices, and I want to type safeguard them to avoid confusion.

This is how I imagine it to be:

```
polynomial :: [Integer] -> Polynomial unique

toValue   :: Integer -> Polynomial unique -> Value unique

fromValue :: Integer -> Polynomial unique -> Maybe (Index unique)

toValue'   :: Index unique -> Value unique

fromValue' :: Value unique -> Index unique
```

The point is to obtain these latter two *total* functions.

But I have no idea how to go about defining this `polynomial` function. Where would it get the `unique` type from?

Comment: Looks like [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) problem.

Comment: This is dependent typing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type. Basically no, Haskell can't do that.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I am not sure it is, since the value of `unique` does not actually depend on anything particular in the input. This is why I am guessing there might be a way to implement it without run time type manipulations.

Comment: I'm finding your question a little hard to follow. Your core question appears to be about how to use types to prevent leaking information but all the talk of polynomials and subtyping is quite distracting. If I've understood you correctly, what you want is possible with existentials or higher-rank types. The idea is to require clients to write a block of code polymorphic in some type parameter. Parametricity ensures you can't leak the parameter. cf [the `ST` monad's `s` parameter](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad/ST)

Comment: Your polynomial example does seem like a rather odd application of that idea though. I agree with @freestyle, seems like you might be asking the wrong question

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I am actually looking at `ST` even now, but it is anything but clear how to transplant the same approach to subtyping. Consider the code in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51502879/2108477); does it make sense if I say I want to obtain any number of instances of `Collected` with `collection` determined at run time?

Comment: It's true that you can do this in an enclosed block, as the ST monad does, but the more general case where you can sling these values around in arbitrary ways does not seem to be possible. I wanted to do something similar with coordinates in my geodetics library (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/geodetics), e.g so that a position in one reference frame was type-level distinct from a position in another. AFAIK it can only be done with values of Polynomial declared at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in an ST-like way you would need a library of functions to operate on the `Value s` and `Polynomial s` types, and then have a function with a type like this:

```
withPolynomial :: (forall s . Polynomial s -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> Integer
```

This will convert the `[Integer]` into a `Polynomial s` and pass it to the argument function. This function will then do whatever it wants, using your library of functions where appropriate. Any `Value s` values are guaranteed not to leak from the enclosing `withPolynomial` application, so they can't get mixed up. However this will also prevent you from storing polynomials and their values for use in future computations.

Comment: This appears to be a sort of a continuation, therefore isomorphic to monad. Maybe we could try to consider it as such and see if it would be useable? Also, are you sure you do not want the universal quantifier inside the parentheses _(because in ST it would be)_?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Type corrected. There may well be a monad instance to be had, but its not a primary feature. I don't think its a continuation monad because the `s` would escape if it was, but by all means try to prove me wrong (I'm off camping the day after tomorrow, so I don't have time to work on this).